# How to get each date from Yahoo finance download?

Tags: python, yfinance

I am gathering Nasdaq data from Yahoo finance.
I got to know to download data from Yahoo finance using yfinance.
I could get Adj Close data but I don't know how to access date element of the downloaded data.

I tried to get date like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cb3UZ.png)

Error message is as follows
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6gPF.png)

I'm sorry I couldn't show you the images directly
due to the policy of stack overflow.

Would you give me advice on this?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of code and error messages. Please copy them directly into your question so that others are able to reproduce the error(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Code to get stock data:

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd

tickers = ["VOO","VGK","VPL"] #Subtitute for the tickers you want
df =yf.download(tickers,  start = "2021-02-01" , end = "2021-02-04")
```

If you want to filter by dates you can use .loc["2020-01-01"] or specify a range.

Example:

```
df.loc["2021-02-02":"2021-02-04"]
```

To export to excel you can use:

```
df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Comment: Thank for your advice. but what I want is to put dates in excel file to synchronize Nasdaq data and date.   I just want to access date field in yfinance data.  I could access directly 'Adj Close' using 'data['Adj Close'].values'.  But 'data['Date'].values' didn't work.  Any solutions?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Could you show what your ideal output would look like? If you want real time values, remember Yfinance can have up to 15min delay. The values that update constantly is the closing price. Adjusted close is adjusted after market hours.

Comment: Ok, let me explain it in detail.

I want to make data with adj close price and date as follows from April to yeserday. (Realtime data is not needed)
Ex) 2021-07-02   APPL   123.23
       2021-07-01  AAPL   122.45

To make this format, 
I can get adj close price(123.23) from yfinance directly using data['Adj Close'].values, but date(2021-07-02) I cannot get it directly.
What I want to know is the way to get date directly from yfinance.
Any advice?

Comment: I think the problem is that the date is the index. Try this:
`import yfinance as yf`
`tickers = ["VOO"]`
`df = yf.download(tickers,  start = "2021-02-01" , end = "2021-02-04")`
`newdf = df.reset_index()
newdf`

Comment: Sorry for late response.  I tried your code, but there is JSONDecordError.   >Exception in thread Thread-1:
  raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: you need to update yfinance. 
```$ pip install yfinance --upgrade --no-cache-dir```

Comment: At last, I did it thanks to your great advice.  I appreciate ^.^

Comment: @Portfedh You are right, after reseting index dates are in column 0. Thank you.